# Error in default commands for pretitle/posttitle

Tags: titles, titling

I entered the default commands for pretitle and posttitle as defined by the documentation for titling to be:

```
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{center}
           \large \lineskip 0.5em%
           \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}}
```

Yet when I do this, I get errors in the form of the red `X` next to the line of text from Overleaf, stating

```
unexpected close group } after \begin{center}
```

for line 1 and

```
unexpected open group { after \end{center}
unexpected \end{center}
unexpected close group }
```

for line 2.

I also do not get the expected results when I edit the posttitle or preauthor commands. However, during compile, there are no error. Is this a problem? If so, how would I fix it?

My entire code is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE }
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.1em}
\preauthor{\begin{center}
           \large \lineskip 0.5em%
           \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}}
\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a small, but complete, code?

Comment: @Bernard I'm unsure what else was to be added so I tried to add code that was small and complete to the best of my ability. Please look above and tell me if this is what you were referring to.

Comment: It is what we need (a compilable code) – except it compiles without error. Does this very code produce an error for you?

Comment: @Bernard Correct, it produces the errors listed above. The only way I have found to get rid of the errors is to remove the pretitle, posttitle, preauthor, and postauthor fields altogether, which is extremely unhelpful. It is, however, error free other than the errors above.

Comment: Just in case: is your installation up-to-date?

Comment: @Bernard I am using Overleaf, so I assume theirs is.

Comment: Anyway, the last version of titling dates back to 2009. When I asked whether this very code produced the error, I meant *only* this code (there might be incompatibilities with other packages).

Comment: @Bernard Ah I see. I'm not sure. It's pretty much as barebones as one could get. If I do something like `\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}` then there is no error.

Comment: Could you post a minimal code reproducing the error?

Comment: @Bernard I'm sorry - was not available due to corona. This is the minimal code reproducing the error as far as I can tell.

Comment: Unfortunately, here I have no  error (and no crystal ball to find out what happens for you). Unrelates, I think, but to be corrected: `hyperref` should be loaded last, with very few exceptions (`cleveref` being the most notable).